# Cookbook location on Chef Server on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra, devops, cookbook

I am using Chef 12.x version of chef, using chef-server-ctl tool.

I am able to connect to the chef server with knife on my workstation.  The cookbooks are getting uploaded and running on chef-clients.

But I am unable to find cookbooks on the chef server itself.  Where are they stored?

Comment: May worth a look also: https://www.chef.io/webinars/?commid=207643

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stored in a S3 like system, metadata (files names, tree structure, etc.) are stored in postgresql, files in themselves are stored in bookshelf by their relative sha256sum in each organization the cookbook is uploaded too.

More insight in [the documentation](https://docs.chef.io/server_components.html)